# Trying to get random element from an array

Tags: c

Trying to get a random element from the 2d array called fruits, im not sure if the printf statemetn with the %c is correct since it just prints a character? im not sure what else to use. Any help appreciated
Edit: Trying to get a random word instead of a random letter from the fruits array, sorry if unclear.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    int isSpin;
    char random;
    printf("To spin the wheel input 1\n");
    scanf("%d", &isSpin);

    char fruits[4][10] = {"bell", "orange", "cherry", "horseshoe"};

    if (isSpin == 1)
    {
        random = fruits[rand()%4];
        printf("%c", random);
    }
    else
    { 
        printf("You didn't spin");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always check the return value from `scanf`, (not your immediate problem.) And instead of 4, you could do `sizeof fruits / sizeof *fruits` to make it more general.

Answer (score 2):

```
char random;
 /* ... */ 
random = fruits[rand()%4];
printf("%c", random);
```

`random` is assigned with pointer `fruits[rand()%4]` converted to integer. It definitely is not something you try to archive.

you want

```
int word = rand()%4;
random = fruits[word][rand() % (strlen(fruits[word]) - 1)];
```

> Yeah, im just trying to print one of the 4 strings at random not a
> singular character, sorry if unclear

Why is it not in the question?

```
char *random;
 /* ... */ 
random = fruits[rand()%4];
printf("%s\n", random);
```

Comment: upvoted - this gets a random char from one of four strings chosen at random. I think OP wants `random` as a `char*` and then assign it randomly to one of the four strings but it's not clear from the question IMHO

Comment: @MortenJensen ***"`trying to get a random element from the 2d array`"***. This array has `char` type elements. There is nothing in the question indicating that he wants something else

Comment: Yeah, im just trying to print one of the 4 strings at random not a singular character, sorry if unclear

Comment: @0___________ I agree that the question is/was unclear. I interpreted the intentions of OP. Also with the `%c`-specifier, I can totally see why you first answered as you did (before the edit). No criticism meant at all. Just wanted to get closer to a solution for OP

Answer (score 0):

To print a string you have to use %s

`printf("%s", random);`

Comment: It invokes undefined behaviour and will not work

Comment: You should also point out the change `char random` -> `char *random`.